# php pdo decrementing the values that are higher than the deleted value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello I am a little stuck on this problem can anyone lend a hand. I have a table which has a column with positions with which they are sorted and what I am trying to do is that when the delete button is clicked for one row the row's which have a position value higher than the one that got deleted to get decremented. As in this

```
 //   1
 //   2 //now we delete this 
 //   3
 //   4
 //   and this get's updated with this
 //    1
 //    2
 //    3

<?php 
require_once('connect.php');
$name = get_option('selectedSlide');
$position = get_option('selectedSlideId'); 
    try{
        global $db;
        if(!get_option('selectedSlide')){
        $error.="No slide selected.";
        echo $error; die;
        }
        else{
        $inserts = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM slider_images WHERE slider_image_name = :names");
        $inserts->bindParam(':names', $name);
        $inserts->execute();
        $incrementAllBehindDeleted = $db->prepare("SELECT slider_image_position FROM slider_images WHERE slider_image_position>:position");
        $incrementAllBehindDeleted->bindParam(':position', $position);
        $incrementAllBehindDeleted->execute();
        die;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Consider if this is needed. If your value is solely used for sort order, it shouldn't matter if there's gaps. In fact, gaps would be a good thing as it would allow you to insert new values (10, 20, 30... and you want to insert between 10 and 20 you can add with value 15). If your system breaks just because there's a gap in your numbers, that's a sign that you're overloading that field and should simplify it.

Comment: There can't be any gaps because in my other functions these values get switched by incrementing the selected and decrementing the place where it goes and it would break if there are gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I agree with Niet the Dark Absol's comment that you should not need to worry about a gap, as long as the order of the numbers is fine.

However, if you insist on it, then I would just simple do an update without a select to decrease the position of the subsequent images:

```
UPDATE slider_images SET slider_image_position=slider_image_position-1 WHERE slider_image_position>:position
```

However, if you have multiple image sliders, then you have to include the image slider's identifier in the update's `where` clause, which images are being reordered.